# Add/Remove Input Fields Dynamically and preview field values in separate div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm building a survey and I need the ability to preview dynamic input fields as they are created, in another div.

For example, here I'm creating text inputs (pretty trivial) and creating radio buttons in a separate div:

```
$('#p_scnt, #p_scnt_' + i +'').live('click', function() {
            $('<p><label for="p_scnts"><input type="text" size="20" id="p_scnt_' + i +'" value="" placeholder="Input Value" /></label> <a href="#" id="removeObject">Remove</a></p>').appendTo(scntDiv);
            $('<p><input type="radio" value="' + crunchValue + '">' + crunchValue + '</p>').appendTo(crunchville);
            i++;
            return false;
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/crunchfactory/tZPg4/15947/

I'm not sure how to get the values, hence the obviously 'undefined'.

Three things:

I want to get the values from the text boxes as they are typed to the values in the separate div.

I want to click in the text box to create a new text box, which, a) only seems to work in the top 2, and b) if a box has a null value, don't create an object in the other div.

Thank you!

Comment: `ID` should not be same while `cloning` and you are `live` which pretty old use `on` instead. By the your requirement is not clear

Comment: If it's for click I would use `$('element').click()` instead of `on`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to get the values from the text boxes as they are typed to the
>   values in the separate div.

I think this is what you mean :)

#### HTML

```
<button id="btn-add">Add</button>

<div id="source"></div>
<div id="preview"></div>
```

#### Javascript

```
// --- Main functions --- //
function _createTextInput() {
  var inputWrapper = document.createElement('div');
  var inputElement = document.createElement('input');
  var removeBtn    = document.createElement('button');

  $(removeBtn)
    .html("Remove")
    .addClass("btn-remove-input-wrapper");

  $(inputWrapper)
    .addClass('input-wrapper')
    .append(inputElement)
    .append(removeBtn);

  return inputWrapper;
}

function _createRadioInput() {
  var radioWrapper = document.createElement('div');
  var radioElement = document.createElement('input');
  var radioLabel   = document.createElement('label');

  $(radioWrapper)
    .append(radioElement)
    .append(radioLabel);

  radioElement.type = 'radio';
  radioElement.name = 'group';
  return radioWrapper;
}

// --- Helper functions --- //

function getIndex(me) {
  return $(me).parent().index();
}

function getRadioElement(me) {
  return $('#radio div:nth-child(' + (getIndex(me) + 1) + ')');
}

// --- Event handlers --- //

$('#btn-add').click(function() {
  $('#source').append(_createTextInput());
  $('#radio').append(_createRadioInput());
});

$(document).on('click', '.btn-remove-input-wrapper', function() {
  getRadioElement(this).remove();
  $(this).parent().remove();
});

$(document).on('keyup', '.input-wrapper input', function() {
  var index = getIndex(this);
  var inputText = $(this).val();
  getRadioElement(this).children('label').html(inputText);
});
```

## [DEMO](http://codepen.io/Tomasito665/pen/grKLKd)

Comment: That's interesting, but in this case, for example, I might create 3 text boxes, each with text (text 1, text 2, text 3). Then, in the other div, I would insert, for example <input type='bullet'> text 1</input>, <input type='bullet'> text 2</input>, <input type='bullet'> text 3</input>. Make sense? :) Thank you!

Comment: @crunch Aah ok I think I understand. Do you want the bullets to also update live while typing?

Comment: yes! :) that's why I was using '.appendTo(div);' rather than $('#div').val($('#otherdiv').val());

Comment: @crunch Makes sense. I will see if I can get something working when I get home in a few hours. It seems like a fun experiment :)

Comment: @crunch I think I got it! :D http://codepen.io/Tomasito665/pen/grKLKd If this is what you were looking for I will update the answer

Comment: That did it! Nice! Thank you very much!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109603/discussion-between-tomasito665-and-crunch).

Answer (score 0):

since live is deprecated I would use this format:

```
$(document).on("click",'#p_scnt, #p_scnt_' + i,function(){
//
});
```

then give each INPUT a CLASS of text-input(or whatever)

```
$(document).on("keyup",".text-input",function(){
   $("div").html($(this).val());
});
```

the above code will need to be updated for the proper div, but it will get the type as its typed for each input field and place it into the HTML of a div.

Comment: Is this a comment or an answer?

Comment: I updated my answer. The change to the `on` is to fix the issue with UNDEFINED in the OP, and the second update will get the text from the input fields.